# Iptables block connection from specific IP - to another IP

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables, firewall

My server with dnsmasq will send Facebook.com (for example) to DNS 8.8.8.8. All other websites go trough another dns server. When i use:sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s 8.8.8.8 --sport 53 -j DROP With that rule facebook.com is not reachable for everyone. I want this only for 1 or more IP's.. not for everybody.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are trying to solve? Looks like you are falling to the X/Y problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Whatever the problem is, I doubt that it can be solved with this.

Comment: Exactly. This is not the way to block Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

To define a source IP for a rule, you use `-s`. In this example, you want to add `-s 1.2.3.4` to your line.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -d 8.8.8.8 -s 1.2.3.4 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -d 8.8.8.8 --dport 53 -j DROP
```

Comment: Sorry my question was not correct.
My server runs dnsmaq as dns forwarder.
For example: www.facebook.com will use 8.8.8.8 as dns server
And www.serverfault.com will use 208.67.222.222 as dns server.

how to use the iptables, to block a specific user(ip) connection to 8.8.8.8. So the IP cant' reach facebook. But serverfault.com will not be blocked, because it's using 208.67.222.222 as dns server.

Sorry for the fuzz.

Comment: Sorry, these have nothing to do with iptables. I think this question might belong elsewhere.

Comment: But it should be possible with iptables?

Comment: @Beginner Something is very wrong with your understanding of something because the comment above is incoherent. What does it mean for a host name to use an IP address as a DNS server? And what traffic are you trying to block? Traffic to a DNS server?

Comment: My server with dnsmasq will send Facebook.com (for example) to DNS 8.8.8.8. All other websites go trough another dns server.
When i use:sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s 8.8.8.8 --sport 53 -j DROP
With that rule facebook.com is not reachable for everyone. I want this only for 1 or more IP's.. not for everybody.